# QGraphicsPixmapItem with non-responsive keyPressEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to implement a basic game...

I press keyboard buttons but the QGraphicsPixmapItem I added to my QGraphicsScene
doesn't move, I have implemented a keyPressedEvent function...

I want to move the pixmap item when a key is pressed.

code is below....

marioChar.h (the header file for my pixmap item)

```
 class marioChar : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    bool flying;
    explicit marioChar(QPixmap pic);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

signals:

public slots:
 };
```

This is the implementation of the keypressEvent handler:

```
   void marioChar::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Right)
    {
        if(x()<380)
        {
            this->setPos(this->x()+20,this->y());
        }
    }
}

This is part of the game class where i add the pixmap item to the scene



game::game(int difficulty_Level)
{

       set_Level(difficulty_Level);
       set_Num_Of_Coins(0);
       set_Score(0);
       QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
       header = new QGraphicsTextItem();
       header->setZValue(1000);
       timer = new QTimer();
       time = new QTime();
       time->start();
       updateDisplay();
       scene->addItem(header);

       connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(updateDisplay()));
       timer->start(500);

       QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
       scene->setSceneRect(0,0,1019,475);

       QColor skyBlue;
       skyBlue.setRgb(135,206,235);
       view->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(skyBlue));

       QGraphicsRectItem *floor = new QGraphicsRectItem(0,460,1024,20);
       floor->setBrush(Qt::black);
       scene->addItem(floor);

       player= new marioChar(QPixmap("MarioF.png"));
       player->setPos(0,330);
       player->setZValue(1003);
       scene->addItem(player);

       view->setFixedSize(1024,480);
       view->show();
       player->setFocus();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to set the [`QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag to your `marioChar` object.

Comment: I tried that, it works! please explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag to your graphics item if you want it to listen to the key events.

From the docs:

[*Note that key events are only received for items that set the ItemIsFocusable flag, and that have keyboard input focus.*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#keyPressEvent)

And the description of the `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable` flag:

[*The item supports keyboard input focus (i.e., it is an input item). Enabling this flag will allow the item to accept focus, which again allows the delivery of key events to QGraphicsItem::keyPressEvent() and QGraphicsItem::keyReleaseEvent().*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum)

Answer (score 0):

Your `QGraphicsPixmapItem` should not inherit from `QObject`.  You should create a controller that manages your `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and will emit signals and handle the slots for all `QGraphicsPixmapItem`'s in your game.

Comment: I updated my answer to  better reflect what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

As thuga said:
"set the QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable flag to your marioChar object"